# Rails: Why does adding translation to a page cause the javascript script tags to be garbled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, macports

Working on making a page translatable by replacing strings with `<%= t(:something) %>` statements triggered a strange behavior, where the javascript `script` tags are garbled.

Here's a sampling:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/jipt>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/modernizr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/controls.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What could be causing this?

For the record, I'm running Rails 3.2.3, Ruby 1.9.2p290, and am using the regular assets pipeline for generating the script tags in dev environment.

**UPDATE:**

I've narrowed it down to the length of the page. Apparently rails (or Webrick) starts mangling the page beyond a certain length.

Comment: can you point out what is wrong with the script tags?

Comment: if you look at the code snippet, you'll see that, for example, the first `script` tag's `type` attribute is corrupted. It's just an example, and the behavior is not consistent.

Comment: What happens if you run this app using a different stack, like Pow or Passenger/nginx? That might help narrow it down to a Rails bug or a Webrick bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was eventually not related to the translations. The cause was an old openssl that was being linked to.

So updating mac ports, and reinstalling ruby 1.9.3 (from source) fixed the problem:

```
$ port selfupdate
$ sudo port upgrade outdated
$ rvm remove ruby-1.9.3-p125
$ rm -rf /Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p125
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125
$ gem install rails
$ bundle
```